# libstdc++.so.6 lacks higher versions of GLIBCXX and CXXABI, can't update

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, centos, std

I've installed [bsoft](https://lsbr.niams.nih.gov/bsoft/) and I'm encountering an issue when I want to run some functions that require libstdc++.so.6.

```
bimg: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by bimg)
bimg: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/EMsoft/bsoft/bin/../lib/libbsoft.so)
bimg: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/local/EMsoft/bsoft/bin/../lib/libbsoft.so)
bimg: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/EMsoft/bsoft/bin/../lib/libbsoft.so)
bimg: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/EMsoft/bsoft/bin/../lib/libbsoft.so)
```

I've added the program to $PATH, path to library of the program and to lib64 to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. When I check strings inside libstdc++.so.6, the needed versions simply aren't there (libstdc++.so.6 is a link to libstdc++.so.6.0.19):

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 | grep CXXABI
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_TM_1
```

I've also tried finding higher versions of libstdc++ - found 6.0.24 on internet, found 6.0.26 that was used in another program on my local machine, I moved them into the lib64/ folder and relinked the libstdc++.so.6 to them, however when I do that and try to run the program:

```
bimg: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

edit: sw should be updated, I did it right before installation of new programs to this machine. also gcc is 4.8.5 version

Answer (score 1):

Solved by finding proper version at /opt/gcc-10.2.1/usr/lib64, this path added to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH